# Translational versus dilatational zero modes?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, yang-mills, instantons, non-perturbative

Why are the zero modes of the SU(2) Yang Mills instanton referred to as translational or dilatational zero modes?

Is this standard terminology?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instantons are characterized by the winding number and a set of collective parameters (e.g. location of the centers of the instantons, their sizes and the inequivalent orientations in the global group space / space-time).

Quantum fluctuations of a unit winding number instanton can either leave the collective parameters unchanged (non-zero modes), or change them. Those fluctuations that change the collective parameters correspond to zero modes. There for a translational zero mode is the mode of fluctuation which moves the center of the instanton, and a dilatational zero mode changes its sizes and so forth...

Comment: I thought I up voted it already. Sorry for the delay!